# Can the compiler implicitly std::move arguments when referenced just once?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-construction, move-semantics

Let's say I have a simple class with a setter:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void setName(std::string name)
    {
        _name = std::move(name);
    }

private:
    std::string _name;
};
```

I'm using `std::move` here, but if I were to omit this and just write `_name = name`, could the compiler implicitly move the `name` argument since it isn't used anywhere else in the setter? It can almost be treated as an rvalue in the assignment expression because it isn't being referenced by name anywhere else.

Can compilers do this? Do existing compilers do this?

Comment: note that in the example given the variable `name` is copied at least once when passed to the function `setName` (at the call site).

Comment: Do you assume that the function won't be inlined? If it does, `name` will not exist, and it will be much harder for the compiler to figure out if using the move constructor is a safe optimization. Inlining the function seems like the easier thing to do in the first place.

Comment: @Domi: inlining the function doesn't necessarily mean that `name` doesn't exist. It just gives the optimizer more context with which to decide whether or not it can elide it.

Comment: @SteveJessop How can a function parameter `name` exist without it's function?

Comment: @Domi: I think you have some wrong ideas about what inlining does. It doesn't change the meaning of the code, and it doesn't prevent the function from existing. For example if the calling code looks like `myobj.setName("foo")` then after inlining it's like `{ std::string __name("foo"); myobj._name = std::move(__name); }`. The variable name `__name` is only there for the purpose of me being able to write the code -- you can think of it as a name chosen by the compiler not to clash with any other name in scope. But inlining by itself doesn't stop the string object existing.

Comment: @rubenvb A copy is not necessarily made. This is an interesting read: [Want Speed? Pass by Value.](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/)

Comment: @Cassio well, yes and no. When passing by value and then moving that value, a copy of the argument is made, otherwise it would modify a calling-side variable. Also, I disagree with a bunch of examples in that article. His copy and swap assignment isn't a copy and swap, and his const-ref vs by-value comparison is apples and oranges. But anyways, I don't like to think too much about these things, and instead write code as clearly as possible (so that it expresses intent, not optimization) and let [the compiler do what the compiler does](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfIQBEf-4U8).

Comment: @rubenvb "When passing by value and then moving that value, a copy of the argument is made, otherwise it would modify a calling-side variable." No if there's no calling-side variable as in `f(g())`. I'm not saying (neither is D. Abrahams) that you should *always* take arguments by value. Do it **only if** you intend to copy the argument inside the function. Exaclty as you suggested, let the compiler do the copy for you (by taking the argument by value) because in some cases the compiler can elide the copy. If the argument is taken by reference and then copied, the copy will always be made.

Answer (score 5):

Adding on top of what [Nawaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415784/nawaz) has [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20420294/1137388). Under the as-if rule, if the compiler can prove that the different behavior between move and copy is not observable, then it's allowed to make the move. (I believe this can be really hard for the compiler except for trivial types for which the gain of moving over coping doesn't exist anyway.)

I don't know if there's any compiler doing this. (I guess not!)

AFAIK, the only situations where an lvalue is treated as an rvalue, for overload resolution purposes, are in a return statement, throw expression and *exception-declaration* (i.e. the declaration of `object` in `catch (type object)`). In addition, some conditions (basically the same as copy elision) have to be met for this to happen:

> > When the criteria for elision of a copy operation are met or would be met save for the fact that the source object is a function parameter, and the object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue. [...]

Finally, notice that the situations mentioned above involve construction. They don't cover assignment as in the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

It *might*  do that **if** the compiler can prove it is safe to do that — it would be an optimization. **But that is not required by the language**. So to ensure the argument is moved, you've to do that *explicitly* as you've done — your `setName()` cannot be improved in this regard.

Comment: Are you sure ? With an opaque copy constructor/ move constructor calls, I doubt the compiler is allowed to substitute one for the other. There is a very specific rule for RVO, in which case it is allowed, however I know of no generalization.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: The key here is => *"if the compiler can prove ...."*. In case of `std::string`, the implementation (i.e behaviour of copy/move of `std::string`) is *known* the compiler. Of course, in case of non-standard `MyString`, it will be very difficult to prove the safety.

Comment: The compiler would have to prove that the copy and move constructor do the same thing, otherwise you violate the as-if rule. And if they're the same there's no optimisation with move.

Comment: @Simple: *"The compiler would have to prove that the copy and move constructor do the same thing"*. No, that is not required in case of `std::string`. In the OP's code, it is very easy to prove its safety.

Comment: Although the implementation of memory allocation may not be known to the compiler, since most compilers allow for the allocator to be dynamically linked or hook. So while in principle the compiler could know everything the copy constructor of `string` does, in practice it probably chooses not to know.

Comment: @SteveJessop: You mean `std::allocator`? The does know (or can know) it. If it can, then there are some trivial cases, where the compiler can perform such optimizations.

Comment: @Nawaz: no, I mean whatever implementation-specific underlying mechanism is used by global operator `new`. So for example with gcc, I think that's `malloc`. Basically: AFAIK most compilers don't know (or pretend not to know) the side effects of memory allocation.

Comment: @SteveJessop: interestingly, I have seen a number of compiler eliding calls to `malloc`/`free` pairs; indeed there is a specific pass of LLVM that does just that (you have to declare the mangled name of the alloc/dealloc functions).

Comment: @MatthieuM: OK, so it's more complicated than I knew. Having initially pretended it doesn't know the side-effects by treating allocation as unknown code, in this pass the compiler will then admit to knowing that corresponding pairs of alloc/dealloc are side-effect free. If you tell it the mangled names of the functions it's allowed to treat specially :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: My question, do those details matter in case of `std::string` being moved implicitly by the compiler in *this* case (or *similar* cases where local variable is not referenced again in the function)? I think, No.

Comment: @Nawaz: I think, yes, which is why I raised it. The compiler won't change a string copy assignment to a string move assignment under the "as-if" rule if it thinks that memory allocation could have observable side-effects. But if the optimization pass Matthieu describes is in effect, *then* it would have permission to take certain liberties with allocation.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I'm not convinced. Could you elaborate using the OP's code? `_name = std::move(name);` and `_name = move_implicitly(name);` feels same to me, irrespective how the underlying memory is  allocated, because in either case, the caller doesn't know anything about the memory allocated to `name` (the local variable).

Comment: The question is, "if I were to omit this and just write `_name = name`, could the compiler implicitly move the name argument". So the question is to compare `_name = name` with `_name = move_implicitly(name)`. Comparing `_name = move(name)` with `_name = move_implicitly(name)` is not in question.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Oh yes, you're right. I meant *that* actually. Correction: `name = name;` and `_name = move_implicitly(name);` feels same to me, irrespective how the underlying memory is allocated, because in either case, the caller doesn't know anything about the memory allocated to `name` (the local variable).

Comment: @Nawaz: Yes, an implementation *could* say that it knows all about memory allocation because that's all part of the implementation. So it could omit the copy. What I was saying, is that on the whole implementations *don't* say that they know all about memory allocation, because they want it to be dynamically linked and/or hookable. I think your answer is correct btw, as to what's allowed/guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: It is possible to detect whether a copy or a move has occurred, though. Take the address of the first character of the input string, store it in an `intptr_t`, then compare it to the similarly-converted address of the first character of `_name` after the assignment. By saying that a move is allowed in place of the copy you're in effect asserting that it's unspecified whether the two compare equal or different, and I think I agree with you.

Comment: @SteveJessop: The copy or move cannot be detected at the call-site because `name` is local to the function, so the caller cannot take the address of the first character of `name`.

Comment: @Nawaz: Oh, I meant that the function `setName` could be modified to detect whether a copy has occurred. I'm also assuming there's no small string optimization in effect (in which case of course even a move would copy data), and probably some other assumptions I haven't realised. You're right it can't be detected without modifying the class -- aside from anything else `_name` is private. I suspect you can argue a conforming implementation could make `setName` a no-op as there's no way to read the value back, but there may be tricks with subclass pointer-to-member to access a private member ;-)

Comment: Ooh, ooh. Actually a caller *can* make a decent stab at taking the address of the first character of `name`. Again, it relies on no small-string optimization, but if you create a `string foo("blah");`, store `(inptr_t)&foo[0]`, then call like `setName(move(foo))` then you know `name` is the result of moving from `foo`, and hence (you'd hope) the string data is at the same address :-)

Comment: So all things considered, it should be possible to answer the last part of the question "Do existing compilers do this?" by writing a test, which is better than examining lots of different asm outputs!

Comment: @SteveJessop: I hope you put all these points and other possibilities (I'm sure there are more popping out in your mind) in your answer. :-)